# Automate / schedule a script

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-platform

I read a number of blog and watched tutorials - cannot find anything to help me with my problem.

I have a stakeholder that drops files into Google Cloud Storage, I have already written a script that performs ETL tasks to.

It would be great where I can create a trigger which runs my script as soon as the file is dropped in a specific place in Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Storage supports [Google Cloud Pub/Sub Notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/pubsub-notifications). This allows you to programmatically receive notifications when new objects are uploaded to your bucket.